# Java command line execution relative to packaging

Tags: java, shell, ide, command, classpath

I have a java file packaged with: `package com.learner.learner;`
The class is called Main.java
The class runs well within the IDE, but when I  try to run it manually at the command line, I get errors ..

> java Main # I am now at the directory where Main.class is ..
>   # I get this error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

How should I execute the program, relative to the package .. ?

Comment: does it have all the classes it needs to load that class ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: It's only one class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the directory that contains the `com` sub-folder, you can use

```
java com.learner.learner.Main
```